# Spark: Best way to build RDD line by line

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an iterative function that generates some data I want the output in an RDD. What is the best way to build it? I can come up with two solutions

1)

```
var results = sparkSession.sparkContext.emptyRDD[String]
for (values <- values) {
   results = results.union(sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize[String]Seq(performSomething(value))
}
```

2)

```
var results = Seq[String]
for (values <- values) {
   results = results += performSomething(value)
}
sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize[String](results)
```

I guess the first approach will be slower but will probably reduce memory consumption on driver and second approach will be faster, but before parallelizing all data will be in the driver? Am I correct?

Is there a 3rd better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: `parallelize` would be the way to go, but why not just parallelize `values`, then `map(performSomething)` over that?

Comment: `RDDs` aren't intended for being built iteratively, and since `values` fits on the **Driver** memory why don't just `parallelize` them? Also, note that since spark is **lazy** and just builds a **DAG** of your computation until run, the first method will consume roughly the same memory as the second _(unless `performSomething` increases dramatically the size of your data)_ - Thus, the best solution would be `val results = sc.parllelize(values).map(performSomething)` as @cricket_007 pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
Yes performSomething increases a lot the size of each input. I am not sure if perfromSomething will be Serializable in order to make RDD out of the values. Otherwise this would be the best bet. Anyway I will test tomorrow. And from all seems that the best bet is either choice 2) or directly make values a RDD.